# Why does my bot command not work despite using process_commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The only way I could get  it to work was adding process_commands in the first if statement, but then the commands would run 3 times, so I changed the on_message to a separate command but that doesn't fully satisfy me at all. Any answers?

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import base64
import io
import requests
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='cytat/')

@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == bot.user or message.guild!=None:
                return

        author=message.content+'.jpg'
        if os.path.isfile(author):
                return

        r = requests.get(message.attachments[0].url,
                         stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

        image_bytes = io.BytesIO(r.content)


        paste= Image.open(image_bytes)
        jpg=Image.open('main.jpg')
        w, h = jpg.size
        w1, h1 = paste.size
        paste.thumbnail((150, 150))
        final= jpg.copy()
        final.paste(paste,(350,250 ))
        final.save(author)
        await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not work". Does it create an error? Does it give you the wrong output?

Comment: No, there was no wrong output, but I found the solution already.

Comment: BTW you don't need to use `requests` to get the image bytes from an attachment. First of all, you shouldn't be using `requests` because it isn't async (`aiohttp` would be better). Either way you can simply use `image_bytes = io.BytesIO(await ctx.message.attachments[0].read())` to get the attachment bytes.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get it to work by using await bot.process_commands(message.content) instead of  await bot.process_commands(message)